# Send values to controller from twig

Tags: symfony

I have integrated google maps in my views `new.html.twig` and I get the the latitude and the longtitude like this in table:

```
<input size="15" type="text" id="latbox" name="lat" value=""> 
<input size="15" type="text" id="lonbox" name="lon" value="">
```

I need to send these two values to a controller to insert them into my database. How can I send them to a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimal example

```
<form action="path/to/controller" method="GET">
    <input size="15" type="text" id="latbox" name="lat" value=""> 
    <input size="15" type="text" id="lonbox" name="lon" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and in your controller

```
$lat = $request->query->get('lat');
$lon = $request->query->get('lon');
```

There are several ways to actually submit the data, this is just a basic example

Comment: juste recupere les adresses mais <form action="path/to/controller" method="GET">  j'ai mis    <form action="{{path('adresse_new')}}" method="GET">  no route found       problem in path how i can solve it .And the values is replayed in url  that's does mean that problem just in path

Comment: if you are getting the 'no route found' error, then that means that your route `address_new` does not exist.  you need to create it in your routing.yml file.

Answer (score 1):

If it is POST request then

```
<form action="path/to/controller" method="POST">
<input size="15" type="text" id="latbox" name="lat" value=""> 
<input size="15" type="text" id="lonbox" name="lon" value="">
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

In Controller

`$lat = $request->request->get('lat');
 $lon = $request->request->get('lon');`